# Guidelines for GUI design for a risk analysis app

Tags: mfc, gui-design

In my free time, I'm working on a risk analysis application. I have already finished the mathematical and simulation engines, but I'm stuck with the design of the user interface. I want my application to be as easy-to-use as possible for Excel users, but I don't want to make it an Excel add-in, because Excel takes ages to load add-ins. So I'm going to use the old and venerable MFC.

I want to make these things easy in my application:

**Modeling tasks:**

- Defining probability and uncertainty distributions
- Defining mathematical relations between the variables
- Separating uncertainty from variability (second-order risk modeling)
- Validating the risk model
- What-if (sensitivity) analysis

**Data manipulation/display tasks:**

- Importing/exporting data from/to Excel and databases
- Displaying nice graphs to the user

Do you know any guidelines I could take into consideration in the design of the user interface? The only examples I know, [LINGO](http://www.mpassociates.gr/software/distrib/science/lindo/lingoxpa2.gif) and [Rockwell Arena](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/tr/5/5a/Rockwell_Arena.jpg), are actually examples of *what NOT to do*. Perhaps I will need to include a simple scripting language in the system but, in that case, it will be an option for advanced users, not for everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For risk-specific functionality (at least, in financial world), one of the important guidelines is to allow easy viewing of summary level risk as well as easy drill-down to details (e.g. enterprise-wide down to security level)

2) Plus, don't forget standard GUI design guidelines - there's always Nielsen and there's JoelOnSoftware's Joel Spolsky's design book and series of articles.
High level,

- make sure your controls are intuitive (do what the user expects them to),
- minimize the amount of work (eye and hand movements) user needs to do to accomplish most frequent tasks,
- Allow easy linking (e.g. no dead ends - if you are displaying a list of securities, make an easy way to jump from security's name to detail screen for that security)
- **Always always usability-test.**

Comment: I'm going to have some trouble with the last item. I don't know anybody willing to test my application. Anyways, thanks and +1!

Comment: I'm not sure of what your life situation is so can't offer specific advice, but since you're writing a risk app, may be you have some co-workers or ex-coworkers who'd have enough subject area expertise and enough goodwill to provide either volunteer effort, or, if you can afford it, a modestly paid test ($10/hr is a good sweetener unless someone's extremely highly paid). Just my $0.01 worth of idea, adjusted for inflation.

Comment: I'm taking a course on risk analysis and my lecturer uses @RISK. It's a powerful tool for Monte-Carlo simulation, but it doesn't provide any facilities for separating variability (actual randomness of the system being analyzed, expressed by a probability distribution) from uncertainty (lack of information about a parameter of the system being analyzed, expressed by a confidence distribution), something that is fundamental in risk analysis, because people must deal with variability and uncertainty in *very* different ways.